Using VPS with Wireguard as source of public IP address
I have a bunch of docker services in my homelab, but since moving to a new place - I have no public IP.
I've came to idea that I could use VPS as source of public IP and route traffic via Wireguard tunnel to homelab.
Connection between VPS and homelab works as intended:
My default/public IP on VPS: 111.111.78.121
Homelab address on wireguard: 10.222.0.2
UFW is disabled
interface: wireguard
  public key: F7AsGVC6EFCWiQcgQWn145/gZfctEYgwOfNUe/ySJl4=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: 5kZyP9lsH8niZ4dlSzsskaHg3Oy/a1HNu2f0fMXbSAs=
  endpoint: <endpointip>:8020
  allowed ips: 10.222.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 26 seconds ago
  transfer: 4.05 KiB received, 1.92 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
root@localhost:~#

And I can access remote service on homelab from VPS
root@localhost:~# curl  10.222.0.2:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
(...)

But I have no idea how to setup ufw and port forwarding to access homelab service via VPS public address.
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.222.0.2:8080

root@localhost:~#  curl 111.111.78.121:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 111.111.78.121 port 8080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Wireguard.conf on Server/VPS side:
[Interface]
Address = 10.222.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <server_key>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <peer_key>
AllowedIPs = 10.222.0.2/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

